# Find keys between $x$ and $y$ in binary search tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-search-trees

Given $x$ and $y$, I want to find keys $k$ such that $x<k<y$, in a binary search tree. Can this be done in time $O(n + h)$, where $n$ is the number of keys between $x$ and $y$, and $h$ is the height of the tree?

Comment: Doesn't inorder traversal with a stack work?

Comment: Look up **1d range tree**.

Comment: @HendrikJan Yes, by inorder traversal i find n nodes in O(n+h). thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can answer your own question now.